# how to access function and its variables define in python class in another python file

Tags: python, class

I have a python file with name file1.py class defines

```
File1.py
class A(object):
    def func1(self, a, b, c):
        # foo
    def func2(self, a, b, c):
         var1=a
         var2=b
     return
```

I want to access the class A func2 and its variable in a python file name file2.py.

I tried this ---> `from File1 import A` But its not working  as I am unable to access func2 variables

Comment: the values passed into `func2` are only available to `func2`, you cannot use `a`, `b`, and `c` outside of `func2`

Answer (score 0):

You're never returning any vars from func2 nor are you adding them as class variables.

Try:

```py
class A():
  def __init__:
    self.var1 = None
    self.var2 = None

  def func1(self, a, b, c):
    #foo

  def func2(self, a, b, c):
    self.var1 = a
    self.var2 = b
```

Now you should be able to create an *A* object in file2.py, use func2 on it and then access var1 and var2:

```py
from file1 import A

obj = A()
obj.func2('var A', 'var B', 'var C')

print(f'This is var1: {obj.var1}\nAnd this is var2: {obj.var2}')

>>> This is var1: var A
>>> This is var2: var B
```

Answer (score 0):

Python, similar to other programin languages, has notion of scope. In this example you don't have access to `var1` and `var2`, they have function scope, unless they will be returned form function `func2`.
To make it working first modify `File1.py`

```py
File1.py
class A(object):
    def func1(self, a, b, c):
        # foo
    def func2(self, a, b, c):
         var1=a
         var2=b
     return var1, var2
```

Then create `file2.py` in the same directory where is `File1.py` and paste

```py
from File1 import A

x, y = A().func2(1, 2, 3)

print(x, y)
```

When you run `file2.py` you should get output `1` and `2` on your stdout

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
you may use another class which would be singleton to register all variables
for example lets say RegisterClass

"""


# file1.py
"""  this is our file1   
we need to make sure our class A has access to RegisterClass 
later in a different file we will access to RegisterClass and 
get all parameters passed to RegisterClass 
Please keep in mind that we need a singleton class as in this example shows 

"""
class RegisterClass:
        def __new__(cls ):
            if not hasattr(cls, 'instance'):
                cls.registered=[]
                cls.instance = super(RegisterClass, cls).__new__(cls)


            return cls.instance

        def append_new( cls, var1, var2  ) :
            my_tuple = (var1, var2)
            cls.registered.append( my_tuple )

class A(object):
    def func1(self, a, b, c):
        ...

    def func2(self, a, b, c):
        var1 = a
        var2 = b
        r = RegisterClass()
        r.append_new( var1 , var2 )

"""  this is our file2      """
#file2.py
#from file1 import *

class B(object ):
    def lets_access(self):

        for item in RegisterClass().registered :
            print( "item1 : {} item2 : {} ".format( item[0] , item[1 ] ))

A().func2( "a" , "b" , "c")
A().func2( "x" , "b" , "t")
A().func2( "y" , "z" , "m")

# now it is time to see which variables were passed to
# our function in class A
B().lets_access()
```